# Syntax error when looping through array objects with apostrophe

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looping through an array of data elements passed to the page and appending them to a select drop down. However, some of these elements have apostrophes in them and are causing a syntax error:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #team option[value='Jimmy John's']

How can I write the following line of code to prevent this error?

```
$("#team option[value='"+teamlist[i].team_name+"']").length == 0)
```

Comment: exactly the same as you would to prevent an identical sort of error in sql queries: escape your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#team option[value="' + teamlist[i].team_name + '"]').length
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to esacpe your value, try this:

```
$("#team option[value='"+teamlist[i].team_name.replace(/\'/i, '\\\'')+"']").length == 0);
```